# Can we upload contracts to testnet or mainnet without being fully synced?

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos

From an enterprise developer's POV I'm hoping the blockchain will one day be as easy to query, and write contracts for as it is for me to connect to a db through a database ide such as SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). If it's not possible to upload contracts without being fully synced, can we make it possible with the default light client features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You upload contracts using a JSON RPC call to a node. Nodes usually don't answer incoming JSON RPC requests until they're synced. The node you use doesn't have to be your own; you could use a public endpoint run by one of the block producers. They should always remain sinked.

Comment: I see a list of public endpoints here: https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/ At the bottom it says testnet endpoints coming soon. Does anyone know if there is another list of endpoints for any testnets running?

Comment: check out Jungle Testnet here: http://dev.cryptolions.io/#home - when you click in organization plus icon it will show you a public api address :)